# Android: placing dynamic scores

Tags: android

So i have a some kind of test and i need some help, I'm a newbie in Android so here it goes. What should i do if i want to post the score of the user next to the textview? is it a separate view? i want to achieve this

[image]

What I mean is, how to place it in XML beside the textview. Any help please? I just need an opinion about this. 2 linear layouts under a linear layout? or 1 linear layout and 1 relative layout under a linear layout/relativelayout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try a `RelativeLayout` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="hi gel" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/textView1"
        android:text="Your score" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="61.5" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    //text.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffffff"
     >
  <TextView
                  android:textStyle="bold"
                  android:id="@+id/hitext"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                  android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                  android:text="Hi Gel,"
                  android:textColor="#000000" /> 

  <TextView
                  android:textStyle="bold"
                  android:layout_below="@+id/hitext"
                  android:id="@+id/scoretext"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                  android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                  android:text="Your LifeStyle score is:"
                  android:textColor="#000000" />
  <TextView
                  android:textStyle="bold"

                  android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                  android:id="@+id/score"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                  android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/scoretext"
                  android:text="61.5"
                  android:textSize="50dp"
                  android:textColor="#000000" />

</RelativeLayout>
```